# Want to automatically generate Eclipse project files

Tags: python, c, eclipse, continuous-deployment, auto-generate

I am using the [Tasking IDE](https://www.tasking.com/support/tricore-and-aurix-toolset-support) (based on Eclipse IDE) for my C/C++ project on Windows 10.

I would like to automatically generate the eclipse project files (.cproject and .project) to perform continuous deployment, but the solution is not clear to me.

I think I could generate the project files using Python but I did no manage to find documentation on how those files are structured (schema).

Alternatively, is there a command line tool which I could use to generate those files ? I am wondering if eclipsec could be used for such a task.

I could as well generate the makefiles directly( without generating the project files at all). But I need the project files for debugging purposes.

Thank in advance. Since I am not an Eclipse/Java expert, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least Eclipse CDT does not provide such a command line tool, otherwise there would be an [application extension like there is for the formatter which can be run headless](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/blob/14561b343f395932078b16a31bbb7acce5ad896a/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/plugin.xml#L914-L920). Both, the `.cproject` and the `.project` are XML files. So the formatting of these files doesn't matter.

Comment: On top of it all, different versions of eclipse have been tweaking some of what gets stored where in the (.cprojects in particular).  Even if they maintain compatibility, expect changes when the application opens and alters the file.  Flowing these back to the generator can be a pain.  To have to edit the generator manually defeats the .cproject purpose as the .cproject is often mostly just a makefile generator

Comment: Did you try Cmake? -- Having said this, I'm afraid that this question is off-topic because it asks for recommendations.